# No matching function when inserting into unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, hash, unordered-map

I declare an `unordered_map` as following:

```
boost::unordered_map<std::array<char, 20>, t_torrent> torrent_ins;
```

and then insert an element into it (in the case the key hasn't existed, this map will return a reference for the new element)

```
t_torrent& torrent_in = torrent_ins[to_array<char,20>(in)];
```

But I got an error message:

```
../src/Tracker/torrent_serialization.cpp:30:   instantiated from here/usr/local/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:176: error: no matching function    for call to ‘hash_value(const std::array<char, 20ul>&)’
```

Could you guys help me explain this error? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

It's because there's no "default" hashing function for `std::array<char, 20>`, at least none that the implementation furnishes. You must supply your hashing function for `std::array<char, 20>` then for your code to work.

As you can see in [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map),:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

you must provide `Hash` for type `Key` to provide your custom hash function.